# TypeError: ( is not a function. (In...)', '(' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I am trying to run react-native-web and I am getting the following error int he browser console:

```
TypeError: ( is not a function. (In '(0, _NativeMethodsMixin.NativeMethodsDecorator)', '(' is undefined)
```

it is stopping in from this babel generated code:

```
    var ListView = (0, _NativeMethodsMixin.NativeMethodsDecorator)(_class = (_temp = _class2 = function (_Component) {
  _inherits(ListView, _Component);

  function ListView(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, ListView);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(ListView).call(this, props));

    _this.state = {
      curRenderedRowsCount: _this.props.initialListSize,
      highlightedRow: {}
    };
    _this.onRowHighlighted = function (sectionId, rowId) {
      return _this._onRowHighlighted(sectionId, rowId);
    };
    return _this;
  }
```

Am I missing a babel plugin of some kind?

**Update**

here are the bits of the src code that mention `NativeMethodsDecorator`:

```
import { NativeMethodsDecorator } from '../../modules/NativeMethodsMixin'

...

@NativeMethodsDecorator
export default class ListView extends Component {...
```

Comment: That's just not JavaScript, old or new. *edit* oh wait, I see what it's doing.